# Deserialize json to List<object> in C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have the following JSON string

```
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "symbol": "1COV.GE",
                "exposure": "0",
                "makerExposure": "-2028",
                "takerExposure": "2028",
                "makerPnl": "447.6688",
                "takerPnl": "-447.6688",
                "makerPositions": [
                    {
                        "name": "IB_001",
                        "position": "-2028",
                        "vwap": "47.41",
                        "pnl": "447.6688"
                    }
                ],
                "takerPositions": [
                    {
                        "name": "MT5_1",
                        "position": "2028",
                        "vwap": "47.41",
                        "pnl": "-447.6688"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "symbol": "A",
                "exposure": "0",
                "makerExposure": "-10",
                "takerExposure": "10",
                "makerPnl": "-4.6",
                "takerPnl": "4.6",
                "makerPositions": [
                    {
                        "name": "IB_002",
                        "position": "-10",
                        "vwap": "136.78",
                        "pnl": "-4.6"
                    }
                ],
                "takerPositions": [
                    {
                        "name": "MT5_1",
                        "position": "10",
                        "vwap": "136.78",
                        "pnl": "4.6"
                    }
                ],
 "total": 2
            }
    }
```

And my goal is to serialize it into a List of object from the NODE "Data":
I have the classes that map the data node fields:

```
 public class Positions
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string position { get; set; }
        public string vwap { get; set; }
        public string pnl { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExPositions
    {
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string exposure { get; set; }
        public string makerExposure { get; set; }
        public string takerExposure { get; set; }
        public string makerPnl { get; set; }
        public string takerPnl { get; set; }
        public OZPositions makerPositions { get; set; }
        public OZPositions takerPositions { get; set; }
    }
```

Do you have any ideas how I can convert the node "data" to list of "ExPositions" objects, eg. List

I've did this but so far it throws an error

```
var positions = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExPositions>(json_string);
```

Comment: Maybe you can create a result class with an ```ExPositions expositions``` variable and a ```int total``` variable

Comment: Hint: start by looking at the top level structure of your JSON object. It has two properties: `data` and `total`. Now look at the type you're trying to deserialize to: `ExPositions`. That doesn't have either of them. The structure of the JSON and the structure of the type you're deserializing to have to match. You can't deserialize the *whole* JSON and expect the deserializer to know that you only want the `data` part. Second note: "it throws an error" isn't very useful information - not compared with a complete error message / stack trace.

Comment: (I'd also strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions, use singular type names for naturally-singular types, and use attributes to specify how you expect the names to appear in the JSON.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in your json - it's missing a closing `]` for the array (I'll assume it's a typo).

The real problem is that you need a wrapper class to represent the `data` node of the json which should contain a list (or array) of `ExPositions`. The `makerPositions` and `takerPositions` should also become lists (or arrays) too. Add the following class and update the position properties of `ExPositions`:

```
public class Data
{
    public List<ExPositions> data { get; set; }
}

// change positions to use a List too
public class ExPositions
{
    ...
    public List<Positions> makerPositions { get; set; }
    public List<Positions> takerPositions { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize using:

```
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(json);
```

It's not clear where the `""total"": 2` property should be in your models (it's not clear in the json because of the issue I mentioned), you could add it to the `Data` class above (if it belongs there).

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cxJujY)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
public class Positions
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string position { get; set; }
        public string vwap { get; set; }
        public string pnl { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExPositions
    {
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string exposure { get; set; }
        public string makerExposure { get; set; }
        public string takerExposure { get; set; }
        public string makerPnl { get; set; }
        public string takerPnl { get; set; }
        public Positions makerPositions { get; set; }
        public Positions takerPositions { get; set; }
    }

public class YourResult{
        public ExPositions data { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
}
```

And then call:

```
var positions = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<YourResult>(json_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [haldo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9665021/haldo) mentioned, there is a typo in your JSON. To quickly parse and validate your JSON data, you can use any online JSON parsers to validate your JSON data. I usually use the chrome extension [JSON Viewer Pro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer-pro/eifflpmocdbdmepbjaopkkhbfmdgijcc).

Also, in the link that haldo provided to the .NET Fiddle for the demo, there is a trailing comma in JSON data which JSON deserializers might not ignore.

Here is the link to the edited demo that haldo provided.
[Edited Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rNtEVm)